# Android - Is it true that the onCreate() method of an app's android.app.Application subclass will not always be called?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I recently saw a presentation about common misconceptions about Android lifecycles. [At one point](https://youtu.be/dcYKW48tHQ4?t=1208), the presenter claims that the `onCreate()` method of the registered `android.app.Application` subclass may never be called if the backup manager is running, and instead only the base class will be used, as could be confirmed by type checking the return value of `ContextWrapper#getApplicationContext()`.

I couldn't find any documentation about this anywhere, and I have never encountered this before. The presenter seems to claim that this is not a bug, however, saying that this behavior is "sort of documented, but very hidden."

I'd really like to know whether this is true, because the application I work on relies heavily on its registered `android.app.Application` subclass and I would expect this behavior to cause serious problems. Can I rely on the `onCreate()` method of my app's registered `android.app.Application` subclass always to be run before all of my other Android components are started?

Comment: The key there is "before all of my other Android components are started". Other than a `BackupAgent`, I would not expect any code of yours to run when the backup is going on. I have this rumor about this scenario, and I have a fair bit of faith in Andrew, so he's probably correct.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've ever encountered onCreate() never being called is when:

1. The activity is a background service or receiver that has already been initialized
2. The activity has left foreground, but is still in recent / memory. E.g activity skips to onPause() then onResume()

This is from Android Dev documentation :

> Restore the calling application from backup. The data will be restored from the current backup dataset if the application has stored data there, or from the dataset used during the last full device setup operation if the current backup dataset has no matching data. If no backup data exists for this application in either source, a non-zero value is returned.
>
> If this method returns zero (meaning success), the OS attempts to retrieve a backed-up dataset from the remote transport, instantiate the application's backup agent, and pass the dataset to the agent's onRestore() method.

To me it doesn't make any sense that an application can restore its dataset without re-initializing an activity. More or less it definitely doesn't make sense that the onCreate() gets bypassed. An activity will always follow its lifecycle and I haven't encountered any time where it doesn't. If a backup or restore is occurring at the time, then it could make sense. Only way is to test it I guess.

Comment: OP isn't asking about `Activity.onCreate()`, he is asking about `Application.onCreate()`.